# (FASM) I can't see the content of a file

Tags: file, winapi, buffer, fasm

my problem is the following: I am writing a software in Assembler. It reads a Windows Executable, and compares the first two bytes if they are equal to "MZ".

The ReadFile API has success in its job, but when I try to compare the first two bytes of the buffer against the MZ sign, but it fails.

**I don't know how to access to the data stored by the API function in the buffer**. The program should jump to a special routine if the MZ sign is found. But, I test the code with a real executable, but it don't jump to the special routine.

Here's my source code: (Short, Minimal, and Reproduces my error):

```
;I use the 4 for the open mode because it means "Read/Write".
;I open the file and Get its filesize for later use.
;The handle was stored in eax by the API
invoke CreateFile, cFileName, 4, 0, 0, 4, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0
mov [file_handle], eax

;Read 8000 bytes from the file
invoke  ReadFile, [file_handle], buffer, 8000, bytesread, 0 ; Now read the full file

;The error is here.
;The program should compare the bytes, but when I test it
;with a real executable, it jumps to the wrong routine.
cmp buffer, "MZ" ;Check if the executable contains the MZ sign (4d5a) in hex
jne bad_executable
jmp good_executable
```

Please help me. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a byte-order problem. From the [FASM manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.4):

> quoted string, when encountered in expression, will be converted into number - **the first character will become the least significant byte** of number.

So "MZ" will become 0x5A4D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer was very useful to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the CreateFile function. The API expects a open mode properly. Apparently, the   open mode is bad, by that reason, my function don't works. Just use a valid open mode, like Read only, or Write only, and it will work.